# How to select data based on a specific date in R?

Tags: r

Below is the format of my data.

```
               Date Cashflow PublicHoliday  Day
    3279 2021-06-25 456.5812    Normal Day  Fri
    3280 2021-06-26 476.0169    Normal Day  Sat
    3281 2021-06-27 426.7399    Normal Day  Sun
    3282 2021-06-28 582.2945    Normal Day  Mon
    3283 2021-06-29 558.3888    Normal Day Tues
    3284 2021-06-30 607.9451    Normal Day  Wed
```

I would like to pick the Cashflow on 2021-06-25 and then replace it with something else.

I've tried something like this:

```
    dfOutflows$Date <- as.Date(dfOutflows$Date) 
    dfOutflows$Cashflow(as.Date"2021-30-06")
```

Comment: Can you also include your current R code?

Comment: dfOutflows$Date <- as.Date(dfOutflows$Date)

dfOutflows$Cashflow(as.Date"2021-30-06")

I've tried something like this. I just want to extract the Cashflow column based on the Date column.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the type of your `Date` column, but a regular subset of the data frame should work here:

```r
df$Cashflow[df$Date == "2021-06-25"] = <some_value>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

# Sample data.
df <-
  data.frame(Date = c(as.Date("2021-06-25"), as.Date("2021-06-24")),
             cashflow = c(456.15, 600.15))

# Just replace "someValue" with the value that you want.
df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(cashflow = replace(cashflow, Date == "2021-06-25", someValue))
```